# How to remove non whole-number notations from excel histogram?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I would like to remove the non-whole number values from the y-axis, and I would like to let only the red cycled whole numbers.

[image: Screenshot about the issue]

There is no option to set the main tick to 1.

[image: 2]

Comment: Try to set the Number formatting to **General**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set major tick mark (Fő lépték) to 1.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-display-of-chart-axes-422c97af-1483-4bad-a3db-3a9ef630b5a9

Comment: I don't find any option to set the tick mark to 1.